# bash du with byte size in decimals to the nearest thousandth

Tags: bash

Is it possible in BASH to do a "`du`" command with the byte size shown in decimals.

For example, say I have the following files (numbers are in bytes):

```
12345 file1
2345 file2
6491 file3
```

I would like to do a "`du`" command in linux that would output the following instead:

```
12.3 file1
2.3 file2
6.5 file3
```

Note: The "`-h`" flag does not work.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use `awk` for this, something like:

```
du -b * | awk '{printf "%10.1f %s\n", $1/1000, $2}'
```

As in the following transcript:

```
pax> ls -l
total 3092
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pax   pax       807 2008-09-14 08:26 combo.pl*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pax   pax       236 2008-09-14 08:26 match.pl*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pax   pax       754 2008-09-14 08:26 mkdb.pl*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pax   pax       689 2008-09-14 08:26 nine.pl*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pax   pax   2089522 2008-05-25 21:06 words.db*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pax   pax   1044761 2008-05-25 21:06 words.txt*

pax> du -b *
807       combo.pl
236       match.pl
754       mkdb.pl
689       nine.pl
2089522   words.db
1044761   words.txt

pax> du -b * | awk '{printf "%10.1f %s\n", $1/1000, $2}'
       0.8 combo.pl
       0.2 match.pl
       0.8 mkdb.pl
       0.7 nine.pl
    2089.5 words.db
    1044.8 words.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `du` `-k` flag to report in Kilobytes?

On Linux, an alternative would be to not use `du`, but instead use `find` to report sizes in bytes, and then do the math with `perl`, `awk`, whatever.

`du` reports disk usage, so it includes sizes of directory entries. If you just want the sizes of actual files, `find` will give you that.

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | perl -pe 's|^(\d+)(.*)|sprintf("%10.1f", $1/1000).$2|e;'
```

If you only want the total of the file sizes:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s\n" | perl -ne '$s+=$_; END{printf "%-10.1f\n", $s/1000}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
du --apparent --block-size=100 | sed -r 's/^([0-9]*)([0-9])/\1.\2/'
```

This tells `du` to report sizes in 100-byte blocks, then I add a decimal place before the last digit using `sed`.

Comment: That's clever, but it rounds up to aggressively. A 948894 byte file I tried this on shows as 954.4. It fails particularly badly for small files. The rounding problem (which comes from the fact that it's actually using blocks rather than bytes) shows a 90 byte file as 41 using `du --block-size=100`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to use the `--apparent` flag like `-b` does. With this fix a 90-byte file shows as `.1` as expected - I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

No, not with `du` alone. You need to use the `-b` parameter to get the finest precision, and then do the math.

Answer (score -1):

In GNU `du` if `-k` won't help (block size = 1024 bytes), you can use `--si` which is similar to `-h` (1024), but reports to the nearest thousandth (1000), e.g.

```
du -k --si some/folder
8.2k    foo
4.1k    bar
```

Alternatively calculate manually per each line:

```
du -b * | awk '{"echo "$1"/1000 | bc" | getline size; print size" "$2}'
```

To customize scale for `bc`, prefix with `scale=1;`, e.g.

```
$ bc <<<"scale=2;1234/1000"
1.23
```